# How to show if function in table?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if the date in the database and today's date is same or not. If yes, then echo a message.

this is the code i'm using

```
    <?php 

    $date = date("Y - m - d ");
    $matchingdate = $_REQUEST['ending'];

    ?>



 <?php  if ($date == $matchingdate) {

    echo "Yes, Same";
    } else 

    { 

    echo "not same";

    } ?>
```

How do i insert this if statement within a  tag ?

This is what my table looks like

```
echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["joining"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["ending"] . "</td>";
```

I tried adding like this

```
Echo "<td>" . if ($date == $matchingdate) {

echo "Yes, Same";
} else 

{ 

echo "not same"; . "</td>"
```

Comment: Just wrap the `echo "Yes, Same";` with `<td></td>` in your original `if` statement i.e. `if ($date == $matchingdate) {

    echo "<td>Yes, Same</td>";
    } else 

    { 

    echo "<td>not same</td>";

    }`

Comment: i was able to add the if statement but now i'm getting this error 

Notice: Undefined index: ending in C:\xampp\htdocs\directory\file2.php on line 5

Line 5 is $matchingdate = $_REQUEST['ending'];

Comment: You need to check if it's set before you try to use it.

Comment: You mean whether there is the 'ending' coloumn in mysql database? yes there is the table also shows the ending date section i want to compare if the date in the "ending" section and date today is same then echo the message

Comment: I don't know why you're using `$_REQUEST`. Your question doesn't have enough detail in it to answer why `$_REQUEST['ending']` might not be set.

Comment: I have a submit form in backend where admin can post certain persons details including join date and end date to keep data of a person. so i'm using all details including join date and end date rows in mysql. $_REQUEST['ending'] is used to know the end date that the admin put in the backend. so i wanna compare both dates and echo a message